# Does a royal flush with 2 wild cards beat a royal flush with one wild card?

Tags: rules, wild-card

We understand that, when playing with wild cards, 5 aces is best overall. This means that one of the "aces" is actually a joker, and that the hand has, say, two aces of hearts, or spades, or whatever. This follows the principle that a joker can be any card that the player designates.

Then is it also true that, a royal flush TJQK(joker) loses to flush TJQ(joker)(joker), since the two-joker hand can claim to have two aces? What is the reasoning here?

Comment: I won't put this as an answer as it's not something I have too much experience with, however I was always lead to believe by people who played with wildcards, that a wildcard can only be an ace or complete a straight/flush. Possible this could be another variant of wild card, I think I heard someone call it as a bug? A royal flush is a royal flush. Wild card or not I think it'd be a chop. A royal flush always beats a flush, even if your flush has two aces due to wildcards.

Comment: I'm not even sure if there are "standard" rules for games with wild cards. If I played a game like that I'd make sure all players understand and agree to some rules first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild cards are typically a "house rule" sort of thing.

I have played a few games in a real casino setting that used one or two "bugs". A "bug" is a card (typically a Joker) that can be used to fill a straight or flush, but is otherwise just an Ace. So, for example, A-Joker-3-5-7 is a pair of aces, 3-4-Joker-6-7 is a 7-high straight, but K-K-Joker-9-5 is just a pair of kings with an Ace kicker. In lowball, the bug is the lowest rank not already present in the hand.

In these casino games, no distinction is made between hands with and without the use of a bug. Players with 9-8-7-6-5 and 9-Joker-7-6-5 would split the pot. In flushes, the bug is the highest rank not already present in the hand, although I did play in one casino that used the "double ace" flush rule: Suited A-Joker-9-7-6 beat suited A-K-Q-10-7.

But in your house, it's your game. If you want to play deuces fully wild (can be anything), and make "natural" hands beat otherwise identical hands using wildcards, that's up to you. Just make sure all the players know the rules up front.